# Nested DIVs shrink to content

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to use a known method to make my DIV centered inside another DIV horizontally, without knowing the inner DIV's width (shrink to content method) on nested DIVs.

**Here's the HTML:**

```
<div class="my-container">
    <div class="my-wrapper">
        <div class="item">
            <span>My Item</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here's the CSS:**

```
div.my-container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 100px 0 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

div.my-wrapper {
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

div.item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: pink;
}

div.item span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**Test case on jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ThZxx/2/

It looks perfectly OK in all browsers:

[image]

except Internet Explorer 7:

[image]

Looks like the pink DIV *(div.item)* is not shrinking to content and taking all available space in parent container.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with IE7, since it doesn't support `display: inline-block`.  You have to add a conditional style for IE, changing it to `display: inline`.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
div.item { display: inline; }
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Change div.item to this:

```
div.item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: pink;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Adding the * in front of the extra display style prevents other browsers from using the style.  Only IE will parse it and apply it.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but i think it's more legit way to use conditional comments to target CSS for specific browser version.

Answer (score 1):

IE7 doesn't understand inline-block properly, but theres a simple hack to fix it by adding zoom:1; and *display: inline; to your css, like so:

```
div.item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: pink;
    zoom:1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

you can read more about the issue, and the fix here:
http://flipc.blogspot.ca/2009/02/damn-ie7-and-inline-block.html

Comment: Hmm, zoom by itself doesn't help it.

Comment: Yep, sorry, forgot you also need *display: inline.